# How to set variable to a huge number

Tags: vb.net

I try to do something like this:

```
Dim x = 1000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

But it gives me an overflow exception.  How can I do something like this?

Comment: Please only ask one question per question.  If you have two questions, please ask the second one as a separate post.  I have edited out your second question from this one.

Comment: And what the *** is such a number for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All data types are stored as bits, and there is a maximum number that most can hold. Learn about the data types and their limitations from MSDN:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7.aspx

Also see this answer:[Is there any big integer class for Visual Basic .NET (128 or more bits)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326319/is-there-any-big-integer-class-for-visual-basic-net-128-or-more-bits)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to perform algorythm on it, just store it as a string. But you can separate it in multiple parts if you have to do it, because it seems that it is not possible to use handle values like this.